# How to check peak in the acceleration column?

Tags: python, pandas, fft, accelerometer, vibration

I have a data frame with the columns 'AccelerationG' for a timestamp. I want to see the vibration/acceleration of the device and check if it crosses a peak value?

```
AccelerationG
0.95
0.93
1.12
1.12
0.95
0.93
1.12
0.95
1.12
1.12
0.93
0.93
1.12
1.12
0.95
5.42
10.66
14.39



How can I approach this?
```

Comment: df['AccelerationG'].gt(threshold).sum()    You can change the threshold according to you requirement, it gives the number of occurances of vibration cross

Comment: `df[df['AccelerationG']>threshold]` gives you the row crossing the threshold.

Comment: can we plot this in a graph? i mean can we do fast fourier transformation, check peak and stuff?

Comment: What have you tried to plot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat=[0.95,0.93,1.12,1.12,0.95,0.93,1.12,0.95,1.12,1.12,
0.93,0.93,1.12,1.12,0.95,5.42,10.66,14.39]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

p.figure(figsize=(10,10))
p.subplot(221)
p.plot(dat, '.-')
p.title('all data')

p.subplot(222)
p.plot(dat[:-3],'.-')
p.title('data truncated')

p.subplot(223)
mn=np.mean(dat[:-3])       # DC 
p.plot(dat[:-3]- mn,'.-')  # subtract DC
p.title('DC removed')

p.subplot(224)
p.psd(dat[:-3]-mn,12,1/0.01);  
p.title('power spectral density')
```

If the data were taken at 100 Hz, over 140 ms, then there would be a frequency peak at 35 Hz.

[image]